# ServiceStack API service RequiresAnyRole always returns 403 error

Tags: api, authentication, authorization, servicestack

I've looked at several examples of ServiceStack's Authentication/Authorization code but I can't seem to get past this issue.

I have created a custom `AuthFeature` which derives from `BasicAuthProvider` and registered it in the plugins on my AppHost. In my custom provider I overrode `TryAuthenticate` and `OnAuthenticated` and on my service I have decorated the class with attributes for `[Authenticate]` and `[RequiresAnyRole("Test")]`. In my use case, I pass a username and password in my Auth header hitting my service, which calls `TryAuthenticate` (and passes authentication), then hits the `OnAuthenticated` method which I fill the session variable with a role (in this case "Test").  The result is a `403 Invalid Role`. If I remove the `RequiresAnyRole` attribute the authentication works, and I can even look at the current session variable and see my role that I created. Additionally I have tried `RequiredRole` and `RequiredPermission` (by adding a permission to the session as well) with the same result.

Can someone tell me if I am properly adding the session with my test role correctly, or if I have implemented the custom auth provider correctly?

My auth provider code:

```
public class AdAuthProvider : BasicAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        var authenticated = false;
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), userName);
        var adRealm = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADRealm"];
        if (userPrincipal != null)
        {
            using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, adRealm))
            {
                authenticated = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
            }                
        }
        return authenticated;
    }


    public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {

        session.Roles = new List<string>();                
        session.Roles.Add("Test");         

        authService.SaveSession(session, new System.TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
        return null;

    }
```

My service code:

```
[Authenticate]
[RequiresAnyRole("Test")]
public class TestService: Service
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use use the `AuthRepository` to `AssignRole` rather than using the session object which doesn't persist.

Have a look at the `assignrole` service code on GitHub to see how to resolve your `authRepo` and assign the role.

```
var authRepo = HostContext.AppHost.GetAuthRepository(base.Request);
using (authRepo as IDisposable)
{
    var userAuth = authRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName(request.UserName);
    if (userAuth == null)
        throw HttpError.NotFound(request.UserName);

    authRepo.AssignRoles(userAuth, request.Roles, request.Permissions);
```

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AssignRolesService.cs